# Bash script to edit excel files

Tags: bash, scripts, csv, xls

I have multiple excel files in this format.
They are clock in and clock out date and time.

```
---------------------------------
| Name     | Time               |
---------------------------------
| Person A | 03-Jul-17 8:15 AM  |
| Person A | 03-Jul-17 10:32 AM |
| Person A | 03-Jul-17 1:56 PM  |
| Person A | 03-Jul-17 6:15 PM  |
| Person A | 04-Jul-17 8:29 AM  |
| Person A | 04-Jul-17 8:58 AM  |
| Person A | 04-Jul-17 9:43 AM  |
| Person A | 04-Jul-17 1:03 PM  |
| Person A | 04-Jul-17 2:17 PM  |
| Person A | 04-Jul-17 5:58 PM  |
.
.
.
| Person A | 31-Jul-17 7:45 AM  |
| Person A | 31-Jul-17 8:10 AM  |
| Person A | 31-Jul-17 3:26 PM  |
| Person A | 31-Jul-17 7:29 PM  |
---------------------------------
```

I would want to extract this data and save it as a new excel file in this format:

```
---------------------------------------------
| Name     | Date      | Time In | Time Out |
---------------------------------------------
| Person A | 03-Jul-17 | 8:15 AM | 6:15PM   |
| Person A | 04-Jul-17 | 8:29 AM | 5:58PM   |
.
.
.
| Person A | 31-Jul-17 | 7:45 AM | 7:29PM   |
---------------------------------------------
```

Basically it's to arrange the data one entry per date with the earliest time for that date as the `Time In` and the latest time for that date as the `Time Out`.

There are multiple excel files in this format, and doing it manually is going to take too long.

If you want to convert them to `.csv` first edit then convert them back to `.xlsx`, it's cool.

**PS: Bounty of 200 rep up for grabs.**

Comment: cc @jacob-vlijm

Comment: Haha, thanks for trusting me like that :). I think you deserved your reputation, and if I post an answer, if it is useful, that is enough for me :). There are nice python libraries to edit excel files directly, but I never worked with it yet.  I need to finish something urgently, and not sure where I will be after that, so I am not sure you should wait for my version of an answer :)

Comment: Hey @JacobVlijm you been a long time friend, that's why. It will be cool though to have your answer - I will wait. But since this is needed urgently, let me see if I can have something working in the meantime.

Comment: Don't wait! It could be over a month or so, in the meantime, please consider accepting a good answer!

Comment: Just a question, I assume you formatted the second column as text in excel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I converted the files to `csv` and used a PHP script to parse the content creating it into how I actually wanted. The result was then saved in a new file then those files were converted back to `xls` then merged into one notebook.

The conversion and merging part was done manually. It's not the best solution but it's working for now.

Here's the script:

```
// get list of files from data directory
$files = array_diff(scandir('./data'), array('.', '..'));
foreach($files as $file):

    // get all data from the csv file and save in the $data array
    $csvFile = file('data/'.$file);
    $data = $list = [];
    foreach($csvFile as $line) {
        $data[] = str_getcsv($line);
    }
    unset($data[0]);

    // parse the data array and get the different sections: name. date and time
    foreach($data as $v) {
        $date = strtotime($v[1]);
        $list[date('d-m-Y',$date)][] = array(
            'name'=>$v[0],
            'date'=>date('d/m/Y',$date),
            'in'=>$date
        );
    }

    // create a new array and save parsed data in it with header columns
    $new = array(array('Name','Date','Time In','Time Out'));
    foreach($list as $k => $v) {
        $out = max(array_column($v, 'in'));
        $name = $v[0]['name'];
        $new[] = array(
            'name'=>ucwords(strtolower($name)),
            'date'=>$v[0]['date'],
            'in'=>date('h:i A', $v[0]['in']),
            'out'=>date('h:i A', $out)
        );
    }

    // The name of a new file in the new directory using this file name
    $filename = str_replace('.csv', '', basename($file));
    $fn = strtolower($filename.'-log.csv');

    // open the file and output the new array as CSV
    $out = fopen('new/'.$fn, 'w');
    foreach($new as $l) {
        fputcsv($out, $l, ",",'"');
    }
    fclose($out);

endforeach;
```

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 scripts you need. The one to convert from XLS to CSV is a command   [xls2csv](http://ferkulat.github.io/csv2xls/) and the other one a script from github:  [csv2xls](http://ferkulat.github.io/csv2xls/) (another [csv2xls](https://github.com/alexprengere/csv2xls)). There are also [csv2xlsx](https://github.com/kyoh86/csv2xlsx) (and another [csv2xlsx](https://github.com/tealeg/csv2xlsx)).

In between the 2 conversions you can edit the files using your favorite tool.

If you want to do it yourself: xlsx files (and the same applies ODT (open/libeoffice) are zipped archives and contain an XML with the data. You can unzip then and the data is in an XML. Manipulating the XML is a bit more difficult that a CSV sure but when the manipulating is automated it becomes rather efficient.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the pointer. Let me see if I can get something working.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @rinzwind I managed to create the following bash script that unzips the xlsx, uses sed to replace certain strings to something else, and then re-zip it again. The script sets autocalculate on, so that if you have any formulas, they are also updated (by default not).

```
#!/bin/bash
if ( [ -z $1 ] || [ -z $2 ] ); then
    echo "Usage: create-xlsx.sh <PLACEHOLDER_A> <PLACEHOLDER_B>"
    exit 1
fi

DIR=/tmp/mydir
rm -rf $DIR
mkdir -p $DIR
cd $DIR
#Note! xlsx is a zip-file
#Note! Original xlsx needs to have autocalculate set
#See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18355691/set-xlsx-to-recalculate-formulae-on-open
unzip -d $DIR /path/to/original.xlsx
sed -i "s/calcPr iterateCount=\"100\"/calcPr calcMode=\"auto\" fullCalcOnLoad=\"1\" iterateCount=\"100\"/g" $DIR/xl/workbook.xml
sed -i "s/PLACEHOLDER_A/$1/g" $DIR/xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml
sed -i "s/PLACEHOLDER_B/$2/g" $DIR/xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml
zip -r /tmp/output.xlsx *
```